# FluentNHibernate SQL Server 2005/2008 Setup Tutorial

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, configuration, fluent-nhibernate

Does anybody know of any good tutorials that show how to configure FluentNhibernate for SQL Server 2005/2008. The ones I have found usually just use SQLite, but I would like to see one that specifically targets SQL Server 2005/2008.

I really liked the sample tutorial on the FluentNhibernate website (http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started#Your_first_project), but it looks like most tutorials I have found seem to only deal with SQLite. It would be great to see a working tutorial that deals with the more common databases in real world applications like SQL Server 2005/2008, MySQL, etc
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tutorials use SQLite not because it's "quick & dirty" but because it's embedded, small, and free. Anyone can download [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) and start working in about 60 seconds, and later switch (or not) to another database *with minimum impact*. That's one of the major benefits of using an ORM.

Just in case, I want to clarify that SQLite is *not* a toy database, for many applications it's enough and even necessary since the characteristics I mentioned above aren't too common for a relational databse.

In the case of fluent-nhibernate, the only difference is that instead of:

```
Fluently.Configure()
.Database(
  SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
    .UsingFile("firstProject.db"))...
```

you'll have:

```
Fluently.Configure()
.Database(
  MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
     .ConnectionString("a raw string"))...
```

Each database engine config has its own specific optional settings.
More information about [configuring different databases in the fluent-nhibernate wiki](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Database_configuration).

Comment: Thanks! If this is the only difference, then I'm good to go. It is my first time working with FluentNhibernate and personally, I learn better by working through example projects, which the FluentNHibernate Wiki does an awesome job of doing.